# Is changing the std::string value through it's address is valid?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, stdstring

I was wondering if we can modify std::string value through a pointer to it. Please consider the following example.

```
#include <iostream>

void func(std::string *ptr) {
    *ptr = "modified_string_in_func";
}
int main()
{
    std::string str = "Original string";
    func(&str);
    std::cout << "str = " << str << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried GCC, Clang & Visual C++. All are modifying the string valirable `str` without any warning or error but I'm not very sure if it's legal to do so.

Please clarify.

Comment: It is perfectly legal, you are modifying the string with the string function.

Comment: Read The Friendly Docs for std::string :) - https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/   and in particular the operator = : https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator=/   .  The operator is overloaded to handle char, char* and std::string copies.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How does the destruction happen for these two string objects?

Comment: See the destructor() link in the doc above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is legal.

You are assigning a new value to the string but are using a pointer to refer to the original string; this is no more illegal then not using a pointer to refer to the original string i.e.

```
std::string foo = "foo";
foo = "bar";

// is pretty much the same thing as

std::string* foo_ptr = &foo;
*foo_ptr = "bar";

// which is what you are doing.
```